# MT7621 Soc Crypto Engine - IRQ not mapped

Tags: linux-device-driver, openwrt, device-tree, amba

I am using the latest Openwrt trunk firmware (kernel 4.3) and have successfully compiled the driver for its CryptoEngine, an internal ipsec accelerator of MT7621 Soc (which as far as I understood is on an internal bus called AMBA / APB).

The driver seems to work (CryptoEngine gets configured successfully by sending and receiving packets, so it does "react" on memory mapped registers).

However the driver is unable to hook up the irq (so it works only in polling mode), because request_irq always fails with error code 89 (EDESTADDRREQ Destination address required) on IRQ 19 (driver log does not give any error before) and I can't understand why (I am not a linux device driver expert, just a basic understanding, let's say that I managed to recompile the driver).

Any idea why this happens ? Could it be a problem with the board dts file ? Here follows the dmesg log and a link to the dts files used ([Dmesg Log](http://pastebin.com/T5VDtEK5) too long to include, Soc dtsi (dev.openwrt.org/browser/trunk/target/linux/ramips/dts/mt7621.dtsi) and [Board dts](https://dev.openwrt.org/browser/trunk/target/linux/ramips/dts/WITI.dts)))

CryptoEngine memory map 0x1E004000-0x1E004FFF

> root@OpenWrt:/# lspci
>   00:00.0 PCI bridge: Device 0e8d:0801 (rev 01)
>   00:01.0 PCI bridge: Device 0e8d:0801 (rev 01)
>   00:02.0 PCI bridge: Device 0e8d:0801 (rev 01)
>   01:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7662E 802.11ac PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter
>   02:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7662E 802.11ac PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter
>   03:00.0 SATA controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller (rev 01)
>   
>   root@OpenWrt:/# cat /proc/interrupts
>             CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3
>    8:      63126      63253      63143      63987  MIPS GIC Local   1  timer
>   10:       1513          0          0          0  MIPS GIC  10  1e100000.ethernet
>   11:          2          0          0          0  MIPS GIC  11  mt76pci
>   29:          0          0          0          0  MIPS GIC  29  xhci-hcd:usb1
>   31:          2          0          0          0  MIPS GIC  31  mt76pci
>   33:       7976          0          0          0  MIPS GIC  33  serial
>   63:       1178          0          0          0  MIPS GIC  63  IPI call
>   64:          0       1305          0          0  MIPS GIC  64  IPI call
>   65:          0          0       1257          0  MIPS GIC  65  IPI call
>   66:          0          0          0       1087  MIPS GIC  66  IPI call
>   67:     144709          0          0          0  MIPS GIC  67  IPI resched
>   68:          0      25822          0          0  MIPS GIC  68  IPI resched
>   69:          0          0      97134          0  MIPS GIC  69  IPI resched
>   70:          0          0          0      43037  MIPS GIC  70  IPI resched
>   
>   root@OpenWrt:/# cat /proc/ioports
>   ffffffff-ffffffff : /pcie@1e140000

Comment: Reboot with `initcall_debug ignore_loglevel` in the kernel command line, and reattach the dmesg output, show `cat /proc/iomem` as well. And I don't see anywhere what is the driver serves your purpose and where and how it is being called.

Comment: Well because the driver log is not included! Here it is http://pastebin.com/vqY7pwUz I managed to make it work on kernel 3.10 without changing anything, so probably the board is not still fully supported on latest kernel 4.3 :(

Comment: Any updates since 2015?

Comment: Yes, there was a problem with early support for the soc by openwrt, now everything is ok.

Comment: I have MT7621 and using OpenWRT 18.06.2 (uses kernel 4.14.95). When I do `cat /proc/crypto` it only shows `-generic` drivers for crypto. How is everything ok?